# Formula to search through b c d and bring value of A

Tags: excel

Looking for a formula to search a number of columns and rows, if they find a exact match to bring value of column A back.

This will be a large sheet with hundreds of rows down and approx 6 columns.

Comment: Look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231916/excel-find-matrix-cell-that-contains-in-a-string-and-return-same-row-but-differ/34233188#34233188) the formula would be quite large.  Look at the UDF option.

Comment: See @Scott's suggestion, but also if it's not too large, an Index/Match array formula might work. (You can use multiple criteria on the Match part).

Comment: @BruceWayne The index match will need to be wrapped in an IFERROR() function for each column as Match only likes to be one column or row.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Ah, I misread his question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to perform this search by concatenating the values of each column into one 'super column', and then searching for your term with a wildcard. The first time that term comes up, you know the row, and the column it was in is irrelevant.

Note that this only works if 2 entries from adjacent columns couldn't create the search term incidentally. For example, 'cat' in cell A5 and 'dog' in B5 would concatenate to 'catdog', and would create the term 'atdo' between the 2nd & 5th characters. If 'atdo'was your search term, it would pick up a false positive on row 5. This risk won't always exist, and would depend on the configuration of your data.*

Example:

Assuming your data is in columns B:G. Make H1 equal to the following formula, and drag down:

```
=B1&C1&D1&E1&F1&G1
```

Then your formula, assuming your search term is "foobar", would be as follows:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*foobar*",H:H,0))
```

Assuming your search term is found in cell I1, the formula would be:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*"&I1&"*",H:H,0))
```

*As pointed out in the comments below, to avoid picking up 'junk', you could insert data guaranteed not to be present in your search terms, in order to avoid a false positive. For example, the formula in column H could be adjusted to:

```
=B1&"|"&C1&"|"&D1&"|"&E1&"|"&F1&"|"&G1
```

Note that because the 'pipe' symbol would not be in your data [if it would, insert your preferred 'special' symbol(s) instead], any search term which starts in the middle of B1 and is continued at the beginning of C1 would not create a false positive.

Comment: Note that this could also be performed using Array Formulas, which would allow you to avoid needing the helper column; you can search Array Formulas on this site for details, but the principle is effectively the same as what I have laid out above (although there is additional complexity to how Array Formulas work).

Comment: Okay I stand corrected,  Building on yours it can be done with one formula `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*"&I1&"*",B:B&C:C&D:D&E:E&F:F&G:G,0))` as an array formula.  I was amiss in my thought that this was a match to my link but that had another level of complexity.

Comment: To address possible false positives, just concatenate some extra junk (characters that would definitely never be in your search terms) between the cell values to act as separators, E.g. `=B1&"-"&C1&"-"&D1&"-"&E1&"-"&F1&"-"&G1`. @Scott's array version of this would be `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*"&I1&"*",B:B&"-"&C:C&"-"&D:D&"-"&E:E&"-"&F:F&"-"&G:G,0))`.

Comment: @JoeMalpass to truly ensure you need to adjust it a little: `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*-"&I1&"-*","-" & B:B&"-"&C:C&"-"&D:D&"-"&E:E&"-"&F:F&"-"&G:G& "-",0))`.  Without adding it to the beginning and ending of the search `up` would be found in `yup` if `yup` happened to be in a row above `up`.  Now it is searching for `-up-`

Comment: Oh see I thought finding `up` in `yup` would be desired, as long as it's in *one cell* only. What I figured @Grade 'Eh' was trying to avoid is a situation like B1 containing `yu` and C1 containing `pu` (which when concatenated would yield `yupu`. Therefore searching for `*up*` would be accidentally found in that *row*, whereas it would not be found if the concatenated result were `yu-pu`.

Comment: I agree with all of your thoughts - thanks both for your input.